# Reusing CCLabelTTF

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to use the very same label in all my `CCMenuItem`s. If I create the same CCLabelTTF once, then I can't add it to more than one `CCMenuItem` because it will give runtime error about label already added. But creating the same label many times also not effective, if the label is same. How to optimally solve this problem?

Comment: The CCLabelTTF creates a texture for each label, even if the content is the same. If memory usage is an issue then use a Bitmap Font. Question is: is memory usage really a current or soon-to-be problem that you verified with Instruments? Otherwise it constitutes as premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use the same label more than once, the label is not only what you see, for example it also contain a position, so you cannot place the same item in 2 different points.

What's the problem on creating more than one? if you have a LOT of ttf labels that change text often you can consider using bitmap fonts. they are rendered faster

Comment: I have a lot of ttf labels but once their values are set they don't change. My concern was memory usage, thought there is some caching mechanism. If not I have to get away with that.